# Let $\{y_n\}$ be an unbounded sequence of positive terms. Does it necessarily follow that its limit equals infinity?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to either prove or disprove the following: Let $\{y_n\}$ be an unbounded sequence of positive terms. Does it necessarily follow that its limit is equal to infinity.

I think this is false, and requires a counterexample to disprove it.

However, I am unsure how to go about creating a counterexample that would help disprove it.

Comment: $1,2,1,3,1,4,\ldots$.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this should work: 1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16. Edit: My mistake this is a bounded sequence so won't meet the requirements of the question. Thanks, @TheoBendit

Comment: @ENV The sequence must be unbounded. :-P

Comment: You only can say it has a subsequence that tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Take the sequence defined by

$$(\forall n\ge 0)\;\; u_{2n}=n\text{ and } u_{2n+1}=1$$

then

$(u_n) $ is unbounded  and  has no limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $(-1)^n+1$ is alternately $0$ and $2$. Multiplying this by any sequence which goes to infinity creates an unbounded sequence that is half of the times $0$. Add a positive constant to make it positive.

Answer (score 1):

0)If $y_n$ is not bounded, say above, there is a subsequnce $y_{n_k} \rightarrow \infty$.

That's all you can say.

1)Example:

$y_{2k}=2k$, and $y_{2k+1}=(1/2)^{2k+1},$ where $k$ is a non-negative integer